# Divide a grid with an undetermined number of columns

Tags: html, css

I would like to divide a grid with an undetermined number of columns.
An example:

grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 90px);

A number of columns are created, but I don't know how many.
I would like to know if there is a way to fill out these columns proportionally.
Let's say:

`.whatever-1 {
  // would take up 2/3 of the grid columns
}`

and

`.whatever-2 {
  // would take up 1/3 of the grid columns
}`

But I am not even close to the answer. Please give me a hand.
This is just an example that I did to help me to explain my problem.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 90px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.whatever-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.whatever-2 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 5;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="whatever-1">Whatever 1</div>
<div class="whatever-2">Whatever 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can try `display: flex;` instead of `display: grid;` and use `.whatever-1 { flex-grow: 2; } .whatever-2 { flex-grow: 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide it into `1/3` and `2/3` then it means that the first one will be equal to half the width of the second one thus we have a relation of `2x`. In this case simply make one of them span two columns without the need of defining any column template:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.whatever-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.whatever-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="whatever-1">Whatever 1</div>
<div class="whatever-2">Whatever 2</div>
</div>
```